# Is it possible to start a workflow while the same workflow is already running?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow

**My Situation:**

I have a SP list with data including a field for the data owner and a workflow that should send this person a mail if he/she has not modified the item for longer then x days.
I created a workflow that gets triggered as soon as a item gets created/modified. Fist I have a local variable in which i write the last modified date + 3 months, after this a pause which last until the date created before. In the ending the mail that gets sent.

[image: Workflow]

I wrote the text just in case that you have problems bc of the German version of SP Designer.

**My Problem:**

I don't know how i can handle the situation when the workflow is triggered but during the pause of 3 months, the item gets modified, in this case it would have to stop/start over again and not just send the mail. What i also would like to know, is if it is possible at all to design the workflow like this, or if it's not possible to start a workflow again before the old one is finished, because there is obviously more than just one item that will not be eddied for more than 90 days at once.

Please note that I'm quite fresh to SharePoint workflows, but I could not find an answer online. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend going about the workflow a little bit differently.

1. Instead of setting a local variable in the workflow for a reminder date, create it as a field in your library.
2. Set that Reminder Date field for the current item of today + 90.  Have that be all that this workflow does.
3. Create another workflow (must be 2013).  Use the `Call HTTP Web Service` action and write a REST query to scan the document library for a Reminder Date that is equal to Today + 90.
4. Use the results of the query to send an email out to each owner.
5. You can use a `Wait` action on this workflow and have it run once a day to have it check for any document that hits the Reminder Date criteria.

This will allow the Reminder Date to change as many times as it is modified without having that document's workflow sitting in a pause state.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This also makes the workflow way much resource saving, because i don't have to run in for every item and can send the mails directly at a time i want.

Answer (score 0):

There is no possibility to stop workflow using SharePoint Designer Workflow in SharePoint.

If you are using SharePoint On-Premise then create web service using Server Side Code and utilize this web service in SharePoint Designer Workflow.